# What's the full story behind Michael Shanks and Season 6 of Stargate: SG-1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, actors

I've been re-watching *Stargate SG-1* and I was a little bit surprised to see that despite Michael Shanks leaving the show, he actually appears in **seven** episodes in Season 6 (as Daniel Jackson and as the voice of Thor) so it's not like he was completely absent.

I can find plenty of discussion about Michael Shanks' absence during season 6 but there doesn't seems to be a *definitive* accounting of everything.

Now that it's long past, the truth must be out there. So, what's the full story behind Michael Shanks and Season 6?

Comment: Others have answered the question below, I just wanted to add that his decision to take a break made the storyline even cooler, as it made possible more investigation of the Ancients and then the Season 8 finale where he temporarily re-ascends to meet Anubis in the diner.  Those episodes were two of my favourite on the series.

Comment: Ego and money. I'm better more on the ego side. it's not hard to see the truth. Don't confuse actors with the characters they play.

Comment: I’m betting he was pregnant.

Comment: I've added some additional quotes. There isn't a lot more beyond what he's already said, but it does suggest some other motives.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, if he were pregnant, he would have just worn a large jacket and stood behind chairs for most of the season.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**The official line is that he wanted to take "a break" from the show.**

Michael Shanks was asked this question at [San Diego Comic-Con International 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20070609002223/http://www.cityofangel.com/behindTheScenes/bts4/sdcc04_2.html).

> *When Michael was asked why he left the series in season 6 he joked,
>   "Because I hate Rob Cooper." After the laughter died down he followed
>   with the more serious response of, **"I needed to take a break from the
>   show. I had a really good year off and then we decided to work
>   together again, it was as simple as that. Nobody expected the show to
>   go on so long and we had options in season 7 and now season 8, and who
>   knows after that."***

There was also the suggestion that he was [**unsatisfied with his character's writing**](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/interviews/ms/0302mscyberex.shtml) in the prior season.

> *Shanks also believes that what he says and what gets into the media
>   for his fans to read are two different things. "I read something that
>   claimed I said I hated writers and denigrated their talents. That
>   wasn't it at all! It was never my intention to insult them. I thought
>   the writing staff was just great and did a marvelous job. In a way,
>   maybe I wanted to stay on the show, but I just expressed that the
>   character (of Daniel) wasn't being made use of as well or as
>   creatively as he could have been. I had begun to think the show would
>   work just as well without me and that's when I felt that I had to go.
>   I also felt it was time to expand my horizons and look to other things
>   as an actor."*
>
> *"The writers disagreed with my point of view. I thought they didn't
>   see what I was talking about. I realize now that I should have left it
>   at that. We had artistic differences, which is what a lot of actors
>   say, but I hated the public speculation that would create. I wanted to
>   be more specific, and it just seemed to cause more hurt feelings. So
>   now I wish I could go back and say we had artistic differences and
>   that's why I left. There is no right answer, given that situation."
>   Shanks pauses. "But," he says pensively. "I am learning to curb what I
>   say."*

There's a hint that there were "**financial reasons**" for his return (e.g. he was offered a chunky pay increase by MGM, possibly coupled with the fact that hadn't been able to find much work over the course of the previous year)

> **SFN:** *What led to you want to come back?*
>
> **MS:** *Without going into too much detail in terms of the business and
>   creative side of it, I'll just say that the reasons that I left are
>   not the reasons why I'm coming back. They're two separate situations,
>   and I'm walking back into a different situation that's much more
>   acceptable than the one which I left. The bottom line is, I don't
>   think there was any bad blood between myself and the production
>   people, except in theory. And, once we actually sat down in a room and
>   talked over some things, those things were resolved instantaneously.
>   So, the situation I'm coming back to is a bit of a unique circumstance
>   from the one [in which I left], and that's the main point. Nobody bent
>   over backwards; MGM wasn't over a barrel, nor was I coming back with a
>   cap in hand. It was more like the situation changed and they said,
>   'hey, what do you think about this?' And I said, 'well, that's
>   better.' And it's as simple as that. For me, on a more personal level,
>   I would say the acceptance of the character and the expression of
>   sentiment towards the character was a factor in me deciding to come
>   back.*

Comment: As an actor, during this period he starred in several made-for-TV films and guest-starred in a couple of episodes of his wife's show (Andromeda) so it's not like he wasn't working. Anything beyond what's above is basically speculation.

Comment: That's completely true, but there was a LOT of speculation out there. Particularly regarding Shanks' salary and the producers' desire to have him appear in more episodes than he wanted to; as you mention, he wanted time off to do other projects, whereas the producers, naturally, wanted him to devote his full effort to the show. I doubt we'll ever get a completely unbiased account of exactly what went on there, but it's possible.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Apparently she asked him (personally) to guest-star on Andromeda so they must have had a relationship at the time.

Comment: Oh, they had a relationship. It was crossing over with the relationship Shanks had with the actress that played Sha're on *SG-1*, as well as several *SG-1* guest stars. Shanks met Doig when she auditioned for a minor *SG-1* role, from memory, but was not cast because the character she would be playing (the Replicator android Reese) was too similar to her character on *Andromeda*.

Answer (score -3):

Your question was answered slyly in "200" (S10E06).

During closing credits, the actor says he needed to do some "real" acting without having someone hurl papier-mâché boulders at you all day.  From this, you can deduce that he perhaps did not take *Stargate* very seriously and wanted something that felt more artistic.  I actually see it in his portrayal. He rushes his words sometimes,  not recognizing the depth of them.

I can understand.  From my perspective, as a gay man having to portray a character on a show with grated mentality toward sexuality... No character development because the science is the star, HOWEVER I think like *Xena*, *Stargate* is a much deeper show than it's given credit for and I think he didn't see how blessed he was. He didn't realize the authenticity of *Stargate*.

Yes, it's formulaic and ridiculous, but much of *Stargate* is revelation and if you respect the ascension plot and recognize the truth of our universe,  *Stargate* is educating people on a reality that nothing else in our culture even acknowledges.

The irony being now he's on that *Hope* show.  Personally I'd be more embarrassed of THAT than *Stargate*.

Anyway the actor...  catches himself and says oh I like papier-mâché boulders,  that's great...  he says that more for PR.  It's not how he feels so i think it's clear that Shanks felt *Stargate* is a little silly and wanted to be involved with something a little more emotion based.

If he really wanted to push it why not ask them to write in Daniel falling in love with a being that is not male or female. It's no queer as folk, but it's a step.

Anyway, if you watch that scene carefully,  you'll get your answers.

Comment: Although a good analysis, your answer seems quite long (and a bit rant-y). The Q&A system doesn't allow for discussion (besides in the comments, although discussion is discouraged) which doesn't suit answers like yours. To get some more traction possibly add some sources from interviews or snippets of footage to support you answer. Also, take a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)!