# Why did Dr. Daniel Jackson's name appear in the Stargate SG-1 intros when no other characters did?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

If you watch through the later *SG-1* openings, most characters simply have the actor/actress names listed. However, starting with later seasons, Michael Shanks has this:

[image: "Michael Shanks as Daniel Jackson"]

[image: "Michael Shanks as Daniel Jackson" (other shot)]

No other actor has a name listed.

Why was the name of Daniel Jackson specifically called out in these opening credits when none of the other in-universe character names are listed?

Comment: Because he had a better agent

Comment: YouTube link is dead. I removed it for the time being but if you've got another...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Michael Shanks only got "and" billing in the show's seventh season, after he was [offered a sizeable financial incentive to return to the show after taking time out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72797/whats-the-full-story-behind-michael-shanks-and-season-6-of-stargate-sg1/72799#72799). It stands to reason that the additional credit was simply part of his contractual negotiations along with more money, better storylines and more words per episode.

Prior to that he had second-billing in Seasons 1-5, no billing in Season 6 (other than as a "guest star") and "*and*" billing from Season 7 onwards.

Comment: I like to think of this kind of credit as "and Person We Appreciate as An Under Utilised Character" ... aka "Sorry we can't give this person more screen time"

Comment: @Kaithar - Yeah, very much so. Chevy Chase (Piers Hawthorne) in Community is a good example. His presence lends credibility and gravitas to the show, but at the same time you don't want to build the show around them.

Answer (score 15):

The "and __ as __" credit has been around almost as long as TV itself.

> Sometimes it went to the big star, but usually it was a way to reward someone who was important to the show with something extra. It sweetened the pot without giving them any more money.
>
> <sup>[*32 TV Opening Credits Sequences With ‘And [Actor Name] As [Character Name]’* by Josef Adalian, Vulture.com](https://www.vulture.com/2014/03/opening-credits-sequence-naming.html)</sup>

The article goes on to list "and __ as ___" credits from many TV shows, including "Anthony Stewart Head as Giles" from *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*.

Comment: This explains what the "and" means but it doesn't explain why Shanks merited it